# how to use a design without header and sidebar as a wordpress homepage?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to use a page I have already made as the homepage of the wordpress site. It's a design made with bootstrap, and it consists of a full width and full height page that is divided in 4 equal rectangles, obviously flexible. clicking on each one of this rectangles should link to 4 different pages/posts/archives.

The question is: how can I change the main-index file in order to have just that design as my homepage, and not any sidebar or header or footer?

Thank you, I tried in many ways, but no success!

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Options` -> `Reading` then select A static page in the homepage settings and choose the page  you want to use as homepage.

You may need to define a custom template for this page if you dont want header / sidebar.

Comment: sorry, this does not work. If you don't call the get header function, wordpress do not load the meta tags in the header and the stylesheet... So i should maybe change the header file, instead of the page template. Better would be to create a new template for the header file, so I can leave the old one for all the other pages. But how can I call this new header template? I tried to put it as a parameter of the function, but it does not work